# TypeError: tf.shape is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to convert some python tensorflow code to javascript. tensorflow js has no attribute shape like tensorflow. Is there a way to convert this line of code ?
[module 'tensorflowjs' has no attribute 'shape'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOa4H.png)

```
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
input_shape = [1, 1, 256]  
tfjs.shape(input_shape)
```

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflowjs' has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: The code you have provided is in python... I am not able to understand why you are importing tensorflowjs module in python... Perhaps if you could share your javascript code, we could help

Comment: @zita did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shape` is second attribute for create tensor function.

```js
tf.tensor (values, shape?, dtype?)
```

[Documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#class:Tensor)